# Implement a function into validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, jqgrid

I see that jqGrid has its own built-in grid validation attributes like

```
editrules: 
{
    required: true,
    email: true
}
```

However, I have a boolean function that checks whether a email is valid or not:

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) 
{    
    var emailPattern = new RegExp(/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i);
    return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

How do I force the validator check emails based on the results of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that use posted `abc: {required: true, email: true}`. You means sure `editrules: {required: true, email: true}`.

[editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) of jqGrid allows you to implement custom validation using `custom: true` property of `editrules` and specifying `custom_func`. The callback function `custom_func` should return array `[true, "", ""]` in case of successful validation and return array `[false, "some error message"]` in case of error.

For example you can use

```
editrules: {
    required: true,
    custom: true,
    custom_func: function (value) {
        return isValidEmailAddress(value, columnName)?
            [true, "", ""]:
            [false, columnName + ": " + $.jgrid.edit.msg.email, ""];
    }
}
```